# Import from Gallery to drawable?

Tags: android

Hello so I am working on an android app that requires me to import the image from the emulator gallery into the drawable to access the image? Is this possible or is there any other way to make this work?

Or is there any other way to get the image from the android device and save the image into the program to be used later?

Comment: yes, you can save image to your application and you can you later, normally you have to save image file path on DB or Sharedprefrences and when you want you just use that path.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13024072/5094531